# Java linked list lastIndexOf not working

Tags: java, linked-list

for some reason my code just stuck. No error nothing. I'm trying to get lastIndexOf object.
My code:

```
public int lastIndexOf(Object obj) {

    Node<E> result = first;
    int lastIndex = -1;

    for (int i = 0; result != null; i++, first = result.next) {
        if (result.equals(obj)) {
            lastIndex = i;
        }
    }

    return lastIndex;
    }
```

Thanks for any ideas and help.

Comment: I suggest you provide a [mcve].

Comment: I think the problem is `result !=  null`. It is probably never becoming `null` (I don't see why it would be), so your loop keeps on looping forever.

Comment: is it a circular link list? that would cause it to run on forever as well

Comment: the reason this goes on forever is because you never change what result is therefore you're going to loop forever because you set it to first and never change it

Answer (score 2):

In your for loop, you are setting first, not result. So the correct code should look like this:

```
public int lastIndexOf(Object obj) {

    Node<E> result = first;
    int lastIndex = -1;

    for (int i = 0; result != null; i++, result = result.next) {
        if (result.equals(obj)) {
           lastIndex = i;
        }
    }

    return lastIndex;
}
```